# Does the pine cone statue at the vatican represent the pineal gland?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, church-history, faith, medication

The pineal gland of the human brain is where the drug dmt is formed, can it mean something?

Answer (score 0):

The Fontana della Pigna or simply Pigna ([ˈpiɲɲa], "pinecone") is a former Roman fountain which now decorates a vast niche in the wall of the Vatican facing the Cortile della Pigna, located in Vatican City( Courtesy: Wikipedia).

The pineal gland is shaped like a tiny pinecone, which is how it got its name . It is the least understood gland of the endocrine system, and  was the last part of the endocrine system to be discovered.          Functions of pineal gland may not have been known to the Romans. It is, however, likely that both the Romans and thereafter the Christians used pinecone as a symbol of new life. For instance, graves of British officers of India, dating back to 1940s and before, have engravings of pinecone over them. For additional reference, please log in to https://tuisnider.com/historic-cemetery-symbols-what-do-pine-cones-represent/